# Footer overlaps content div

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to resolve the issue as to why the footer is covering the content div. I see that the content div is not expanding, but not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the updated css: (I made some changes to make the footer a sticky footer)

```
 * {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    }

html, body {
    height:100%;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

#wrap {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0 0 -159px 0; 
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    }

#toprow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 108px;
    background-color:#000000;
}

#toprow-outer {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

#main {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 0 0 159px 0;
}

#content {
    margin:0 auto;
    /*width:898px;*/
    width: 804px;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 37px;
    padding-left: 47px;
    padding-right: 47px;
    padding-bottom: 47px;
}

#content p {
    line-height:16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p.first {
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height:16px;
}

.bottomSpacerRow {
    height: 47px;
    background-color: #DF2529;
    clear:left;
}

h2{
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
    font-size:28px;
    color:#000000;
    margin-bottom:26px;
}

#masthead {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 898px;
    height: 108px;
}

#logo {
    width: 331px;
    height: 74px;
    margin-top:17px;
    margin-right:38px;
    margin-bottom:17px;
    float:left;
}

#masthead-spacerbot {
    height: 15px;
}

h3 {
    font:"Myriad Pro";
    font-size:25px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-bottom:26px;
}

#pic-nathan {
    width: 155px;
    height: 199px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
}

h4 {
    font:"Myriad Pro";
    font-size:18px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom:26px;
}

.text {
    font:Myriad Pro;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#textspacer {
    height: 15px;
}

button {
    width:59px;
    height:27px;
    line-height:27px;
    background-color:#9e9d9e;
    border:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left;
}



.clear {
    clear:both;
}

.clearfooter {
    clear:both;
    height: 47px;
}


.linebreak {
    clear:left;
    }

#footer {
    position: relative;
    min-height:132px;
    padding-top:27px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}

a.footer {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.footer:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#footercontent-outer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1024px;
}

#footercontent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:898px;
    background-color:#C1AA47;
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
    font-size:13px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footer-linebreak {
    clear:left;
    height:7px;
}

#footercol {
    width: 224px;
    float:left;
    /*background-color: #DCE81F;*/
}

#footercol-links {
    width: 169px;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 55px;
}

#footercol-contact {
    width: 224px;
    float:left;
}

#footer UL
{
    list-style-type: none;
    width:224px;
}

#footercol-right {
    width: 194px;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 30px;
}


#footerLogo {
    width:148px;
    height: 33px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:23px;
}

#footerinfo {
    clear:left;
    margin-left:21px;
    font-size:12px;
}

h5 {
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom:17px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:normal;
}

#icon-footer{
    width:35px;
    height:24px;
    float:left;
}

#icon-text {
    float:left;
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:24px;
}
```

here is the updated html code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="locks, lock & key, locksmiths, locksmithing, charles town wv, key locksmith, auto locksmith, rekeying locks">
<title>UrgenKey - Services</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-sub-teststicky.css">
<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap">

<div id="toprow">
<div id="toprow-outer">
<div id="masthead">
<div id="logo" title="UrgenKey Locksmith Service"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo.jpg" width="331" height="74"  alt=""/></a>
</div>

<div id="topnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" class="btnhome">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html" class="btnabout">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btnsvcsSel">SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html" class="btncontact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--end topnav-->

</div><!--end masthead-->
</div><!--end toprow outer-->
</div><!--end toprow -->

<div id="main">

<div id="content">

<h2>Services</h2>

  <p class="first">UrgenKey Locksmith Service is owned and operated by Nathaniel Rhodes. 
Nathaniel completed training throuogh Penn Foster and became certified in February of 2012.</p>

</div>
<!--end content-->

</div><!--end main-->

</div><!--end wrap-->

<div id="footer">
<div id="footercontent-outer">
<div id="footercontent">
<div id="footercol">
<div id="footerLogo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo-footer.jpg" width="148" height="33" alt="UrgenKey Locksmith Service"/></a></div><!--end footerlogo-->
<div id="footerinfo">
© 2014 Urgenkey<br> 
Limited Liability<br>
Licensed & Insured<br>
Bonded</div>
</div><!--end footercol1-->
<div id="footercol-links"><h5>LINKS</h5>
<div class="linebreak"></div>
<UL>
<li><a href="#" class="footer">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="footer">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="footer">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="footer">Contact</a></li>
</UL>
</div><!--end footercol-links-->

<div id="footercol-contact"><h5>CONTACT</h5>
<div class="linebreak"></div>
<UL>
<li><a href="#" class="footer">Nathan@UrgenKey.com</a></li>
<li>540-664-0765</li>
</UL>

</div>
<div id="footercol-right"><h5>CONNECT</h5>
<div class="linebreak"></div>
<div id="icon-footer"><img src="images/icon-facebook.png" width="26" height="24" alt=""/></div> 
<div id="icon-text"><a href="#" class="footer">FaceBook</a></div> 
<div id="footer-linebreak"></div>
<div id="icon-footer"><img src="images/icon-twitter.png" width="26" height="25" alt=""/></div> 
<div id="icon-text"><a href="#" class="footer">Twitter</a></div>
</div><!--end footercol-right-->

</div><!--end footercontent-->
</div><!--end footercontent-outer-->
</div><!--end footer-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you set the wrap ***height to 100%*** .Remove that .It only needs `min-height`.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UjXFy/1/

Fullscreen output : http://jsfiddle.net/UjXFy/1/show/

```
#wrap {
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But now when I only have a few lines of text, the content div does not expand to the footer. I tried adding overflow visible to content div but it did not work.

Comment: Can you make the edit in the above fiddle and comment it?I will see that and solve your problem.

Comment: I have made the edit. Here is the css and html after making the edit you suggested. The problem is that the content div does not fill the browser height to 100%.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the updated css and html. Thank you for helping me with this!!